# Find intersections of dictionary keys and combine them

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, intersection

So I am on a problem.
I have this function where I get a list containing dictionaries as an input and the output should be a new dictionary with keys that are all in the input dictionaries and as value a list which contains all the values the keys had.

E.G.

```
d1 = {1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40, 5: 50}

d2 = {1: 20, 3: 60, 5: 100}

d3 = {1: 10, 7: 70, 5: 55}

print find_intersection([d1, d2, d3])
# prints {1: [10, 10, 20], 5: [50, 55, 100]}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: See [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and its examples and give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

If you find the `keys()` intersection first, you can make the dictionary with a comprehension.

You can reduce() (thanks UltraInstinct) over the dictionaries with `__and__` to build the intersection of the keys.

```
import operator
# python 3
# from functools import reduce

dicts = [
   {1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40, 5: 50},
   {1: 20, 3: 60, 5: 100},
   {1: 10, 7: 70, 5: 55}
]

keys = reduce(operator.__and__, map(set, dicts)

{k: [d[k] for d in [d1, d2, d3]] for k in keys}

# {1: [10, 20, 10], 5: [50, 100, 55]}
```

Comment: .. and if there a variable number of input lists: `keys = reduce(operator.__and__, map(set, input_lists)`.

Comment: yeah! That's what I was looking for @UltraInstinct. Thanks.

Comment: That's pretty cool. I didn't know that dict.keys() supported the `&`  operator. Does this work in python 2 as well, or do they need to use dict.viewkeys() instead? The question code uses `print` as a keyword, so I guess they are not using python 3.

Comment: @MarkMeyer  Sure! Actually, seeing as OP is probably using Python2, you might want to update your answer.

Comment: @HåkenLid: In python3, yes. In Python2, no (`{}.keys()` returns a list).

Comment: Looks like it should also work in python 2 if you use dict.viewkeys(), according to the docs: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single for loop. Any key that is not present in every input dictionary will raise a KeyError

```
def find_intersection(dicts):
    retval = {}
    for key in dicts[0]:
        try:
            retval[key] = [d[key] for d in dicts]
        except KeyError:
            pass
    return retval
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use[`defaultdic`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) and append the values to the keys. After that just look for values with length 3 and you have the key intersections.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
d1 = {1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40, 5: 50}
d2 = {1: 20, 3: 60, 5: 100}
d3 = {1: 10, 7: 70, 5: 55}

for dic in [d1,d2,d3]:
    for k,v in dic.iteritems():
        d[k].append(v)
```

d outputs:

```
defaultdict(list,
    {1: [10, 20, 10],
     2: [20],
     3: [30, 60],
     4: [40],
     5: [50, 100, 55],
     7: [70]})
```